# How to retrieve AWS Private Key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I missed my .ppk file, and now i want to access my EC2 files, there is any solutions to retrieve my .ppk file?

I just tried to create a new key pair in that instance but it does not working.

Comment: Let's use the front door of a house as an example. The lock is the public key and the key in your pocket is the private key. You can use the private key to open the door. However, if you lose the front door key (the private key), you can't open the lock. Making a new key won't let you in either, since it doesn't match the lock (the public key). This is good, otherwise I could make a key and use it to get into _your_ house. If you have lost your key, the only choice is to replace the lock. This involves putting a new public key int the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file per @jweyrich's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you lost the key and cannot recover it, you can still regain access to the EC2. You may try one of these:

1. Generate an AMI from the EC2 and restore it to a new EC2, which will let you pick a new key for the instance.
2. Stop the instance, detach the root volume from it, attach it to another EC2 that you have access, mount the root volume, and change the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the user that you use to login.

A 3rd option, but less common, would require you to have Systems Manager's agent configured on the EC2. From the SSM you could run a playbook/recipe to change the same file mentioned in option 2.